# Regsitration form on External page

Tags: user-registration

I am trying to achieve where user can register from my another website which is in sub folder and in the same database. However both website has own tables and one is Wordpress and other is non-wordpress website.

Means `www.wordpress-site.com` is my wp site and I want to place registration form where site is `www.wordpress-site.com/other-site/`

Once user register it should redirect to the same/current page and not to any of wordpress pages.

I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`...